# What is Manifest for Web Application, and do we need it?

Tags: seo, meta-tags, google-chrome, meta-description, meta-keywords

> Web Application [Manifests](http://w3c.github.io/manifest/): Starting in Chrome 39, Manifests let developers wrap metadata about a Web application into a single file, reducing duplication and saving a bit of bandwidth. Adding apps to the homescreen is as easy as defining a title, landing page, default orientation, and multiple icons depending on size and screen density.

Source: [Chrome 39 beta arrives with new developer features, including JavaScript Generators and Web Animations control](http://venturebeat.com/2014/10/09/chrome-39-beta-arrives-with-new-developer-features/) (Oct 9, 2014)

---

When should we as professionals begin implementing this feature? I'm a bit unclear on what it is --- will all websites need to migrate to this, or only "Web Applications." For example would a blog or company info type of website need this in the immediate, or for now is it only for web applications with heavy mobile usage? I see the page references *Default Orientation* which leads me to believe it's more for Web Apps currently.

Comment: I'd say "not yet" based on the warnings on the top of the page: "Implementors need to be aware that this specification is extremely unstable. **Implementors who are not taking part in the discussions will find the specification changing out from under them in incompatible ways.**". If Chrome's the only browser currently implementing this, you're still going to need to implement the fallbacks anyway for now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the *Editors Draft* has been updated even as recently as yesterday (17-Nov-2014), the last *Working Draft* was published nearly a year ago (Dec-2013) and will be unstable, potentially completely incompatible with each next draft/phase and would not yet be deemed ready for use.

I would certainly suggest you hold off implementation until it reaches the Candidate Recommendation (CR) phase - those who introduce features into browsers and devices will be waiting until this time.

You can keep checking the status if you wish by watching the Maturity column on the 
[W3C Standards for Web Applications on Mobile: Current State and Roadmap](http://www.w3.org/Mobile/mobile-web-app-state/) page, where you can see this feature is currently not yet supported by any major browsers.